# Opposite of "the last one"

Tags: questions, sentence-patterns

Let's say there is a group of people that takes turns in carrying out a certain task.
This task can be done by other people outside the group, and members of the group can repeat the same task over time.

I am looking for the opposite form of "Who was the last person to carry out the task"?
**Would the question "Who hasn't done the task the longest?" be correct?**

To deepen the example let's take the following scenario:

- 60 days ago the task was completed by Person A
- 50 days ago the task was completed by Person B
- 40 days ago the task was completed by Person C
- 30 days ago the task was completed by Person B
- 20 days ago the task was completed by Person B

I want to find out who has NOT done the task in the longest time (Person A) - or the opposite of the last person who has completed the task.

What would be the right question to find out?

Comment: In your set of examples, B is the **latest** or **last** person to do the job, and **A** is the **first** or **earliest** person to do the job.

Comment: ............... 'Who's due?' // 'Whose latest turn was least recent?'

Comment: "Who did the task least recently?"

Comment: @Dan ah that would work!

Comment: @Greybeard thank you for your comment but A is not the first person (others might have done the task before him)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say:

> Who's gone the longest since doing the dishes?

If the "task" is something people want to do, you could replace *gone* with *waited* or a similar verb.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: So just to be clear, saying "Who hasn't done the dishes the longest?" is not correct?

Comment: *Who hasn't done the dishes the longest* sounds very strange to me; I don't believe it's something a native English speaker would say.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is very unclear to me, but since you used "Who hasn't done the task the longest?" as a reference to your objective, I would suggest **"Who was unable to carry out the task the longest?"** or **"Who was struggling to complete the task the longest?"**